# How to create docker image of kafka v0.11

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

At my company, we will add functionalities to kafka (for internal use) so will need to create my own docker images of kafka with the additions going forward.

I know there are some v0.11 images out there but how do I create it myself so I can get some practice creating kafka docker images.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, got to https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/. There you can find on the right hand side the link to the Github repository where the Dockerfile resides -> https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker.

Open the Dockerfile and try to figure out how others are creating an Docker image for the needed software -> https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile

This way you can learn a lot and you can follow the experience of others in creating Docker images.